# Saving pictureBox Image on Network Folder

Tags: c#, picturebox

i want to save picturebox image in a share folder on network
i use this code
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"192.168.1.39\xxxxxx", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

but it rauses error
please help me!

xxxxxx is name of shahre folder

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

A literal reading of your question ("xxxxxx is name of share folder") suggests that you're making a call like:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"192.168.1.39\myshare",
                         System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

You'll need to specify the name of the file you want to create:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"192.168.1.39\myshare\myfile.jpg",
                         System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use the IP of machine in order to access its disk.
Try mapping the network folder as local drive on your machine, e.g. Z: and then:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"Z:\xxxxxx", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```